# facebook friends birthday is not coming in facebook graph api android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my app i am pulling facebok friend's birthday. i am login in facebook with an userid and getting friend's birthday perfectly.but with an another specific user id i am getting null in all friend's birthday field.So i want to know whethere there is any privacy in facebook for pulling friend's details or i have to modify my code.So my question is only for tha specific user id i am not getting friend's birthday.But in normal facebook browser i can seefriend's birthday and not in my app.i am giving permissions `'user_birthday', 'friends_birthday'`.Plz help me.Thank u

Answer (score 1):

If you go into your facebook settings (on the website), and go to the "Apps" section, you'll see there's an "Apps others use" subsection, where you can limit the data that apps can access through your friends.

From there, you can turn off "Birthday", along with a whole host of other info. So if you're seeing null for birthday, it's likely that they've turned it off.